# Sticky nav won't scroll on short pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm developing a site for a florist and am currently testing and refining it. A long-standing issue is with the navbar, which is supposed to stick to the top of the page when the user scrolls past it. This works fine on longer pages, but on short pages where the screen resolution is small and the nav "spills" past the end of the page scrolling doesn't work - when the nav sticks using jQuery and position: fixed the page jumps back to the top once the user scrolls past. (For an example see http://efbeta.nzrailphotos.co.nz/products/teddies/). How can I fix this so that either:

- the navbar doesn't fix when page content is shorter than the navbar
- the navbar scrolls on short pages

```
function sticky_relocate()
{
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('nav').addClass('stick')
  else
    $('nav').removeClass('stick'); 
}
$(function()
{
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

Comment: where is your jquery codes? Post it here so that we can see what is wrong

Comment: or make a jsfiddle that is much better.

Comment: function sticky_relocate() {
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top)
            $('nav').addClass('stick')
        else
            $('nav').removeClass('stick');
 }
        $(function() {
            $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
            sticky_relocate();
        });

Comment: [I also have this issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837871/javascript-fixed-position-nav-works-intermittently-depending-on-window-height-am?lq=1) - disappointing the only 'solution' here was to stop using sticky navigation...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Jquery plugin called StickyJS can help you : http://stickyjs.com

Comment: That didn't make a difference.

Comment: I've taken the sticky navbar off due to issues, so it's not there any more. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your minimum page height needs to be at least as high as the fully expanded nav bar.  Try setting the #container style to a min-height.

Comment: While expanding the navbar to work out the max height I realised that the bottom of it isn't accessible... whoops :/

Comment: Yeah.  It may be better to use an 'accordian' or 'popout' style menu instead so that you cannot expand all the menu items at the same time.

Comment: In any case, if you set #container to min-height: 2000px; it will fix your problem (though this is definately not an ideal solution).

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to change the navbar style. Would probably look a bit better too...