# Javascript fixed position nav works intermittently depending on window height/amount of scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a header image above a navigation bar, the header image is comprised of two images, the one in the foreground is in the lower-left, and scrolls with the background until it's passed some way off the top of the screen, then it overflows into the navigation, and finally scrolls up with it until the navigation fixes at the top.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgm4G/)

Change the height of the output window to see the problem I describe below.

```
$(function () {
    var nav_offset_top = $('#nav').offset().top;
    var nav = function () {
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (scroll_top < 195) {
            $('#fg-img').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': 0 });
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }
        else if (scroll_top < 265) {
            $('#fg-img').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': -195});
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }
        else if (scroll_top < nav_offset_top) {
            $('#fg-img').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 70-scroll_top });
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }
        else {
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 0 });
            $('#fg-img').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': -247  });
        }
        
    };
    nav();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        nav();
    });

});
```

This works exactly as I intend if the Chrome window is say, half the vertical height of my screen - so I initially assumed it was working perfectly.

I then realised however that is does *not* work if there is 'not much' to scroll down to - when `scroll_top == nav_offset_top` the whole thing 'jumps' back up.

This is the [same issue as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905700/sticky-nav-wont-scroll-on-short-pages?rq=1) - but that went unsolved, and the OP 'resolved' it by not using a fixed navigation...

Probably [also the same issue as asked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470892/not-able-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-when-sticky-headers-position-chang?rq=1), but that too was abandoned without answer.

HTML looks like:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="content">
        <img id="fg-img" src="img/fg.png" />
        <img class="banner" width="960px" height="300px" src="img/bg.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="nav">
</div>
```

Comment: would you mind posting a cut back version of you `html` please

Comment: or creating a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Added HTML. @rob when I try to create a fiddle, it works even less - I can't make it fix the navigation at all. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I created a fiddle to try understanding your question but everything works as it's coded... http://jsbin.com/puxom/1/edit

Comment: @haxxxton - I just realised the issue isn't window size, per se, it's that there is not much to scroll down to. I *guess* it needs 52px to scroll down to - that's 252-197. But how do I work around?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto No it doesn't - in your fiddle `#nav` isn't sticking to the top at all.

Comment: yes it is ... you just have to scroll it down ... a lot ... it might be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve if you post the images, or a similar website

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Sorry, no. Not for me. I've scrolled to the bottom. nav disappeared off the top. Struggling to find similar site.

Comment: http://corp.ign.com/ - imagine the 'IGN' badge stays there as you scroll down, until it reaches the navigation, and then stays in/on the nav bar, which fixes at the top.

Comment: write error, double `else`

Comment: @rob Created fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sgm4G/ - change height of output window to see effect when scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it.

The issue was that I was letting the main body of content 'jump' up behind the navigation is soon as it stuck.

I actually didn't notice this behaviour at first - since I was just using a load of `<br />`s to fill some dummy content.

So, when the window size was big enough to allow scrolling down to meet the `#nav` div, and slightly beyond, but not so large as to have content beyond the amount by which it jumps up behind `#nav`, the browser would not let it scroll beyond the end of the page, and thus 'jumps' back up.

My fix is to cloak `#nav` in some outer `#sticky-nav{ min-height: /*height of everything that sticks to top */ }`.

Simple, but it works. jQuery is the same, we're still detecting off and sticking `#nav`, but now the content won't jump behind it, so it won't flicker when there's an amount of scroll somewhere between 0 and nav height.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgm4G/1/).

Answer (score -1):

```
else{
            $('#fg-img').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': -247});
        }
```

change in

```
else if (scroll_top < ('you condition')  ){
            $('#fg-img').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': -247});
        }
```

Comment: `else if` with no condition..?

Comment: you're right. you can delete it, because that line does not work

Comment: It works as I have it, with no `if`. If all other conditions fail, `else` takes effect.

Comment: as you like. have double `else` only works on the last Jquery

Answer (score -1):

### [Solution](http://jsbin.com/puxom/2/edit)

Tried to dry the elements as much as possible for a clean solution.
Notice that if you remove the block display from the images you will have to set the line-height or you might end up with a space between the elements.

#### HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/960x300" />
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/960x80/000000" />
</div>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

#### CSS

```
body {margin: 0}
img {display: block}
ol {margin: 10px; padding: 0 0 0 20px}
```

#### JS

```
var $nav = $('#nav'), 
    $header = $('#header'),
    $window = $(window),
    height = $nav.height(),
    top = $nav.offset().top,

nav = function () {  
  var scroll = $window.scrollTop(); 
  if (top < scroll) {
    $nav.css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 0});        
    $header.css({ 'margin-bottom': height + 10 });
    //10 is the bottom margin of the next element
  } else {
    $nav.css({ 'position': 'relative' });
    $header.css({ 'margin-bottom': 0 });
  }
};  

nav();
$window.scroll(nav);
```

Comment: I already have that much working - the issue is that when I add the overlayed image that scrolls down and fixes in the fixed nav, it starts jumping if the page isn't tall enough (i.e. not enough `ol` elements in your example).

Comment: What I posted in OP works fine, as long as there's enough content on the page. If it gets to `#nav` and there's not much scroll left, it gets all jumpy.

Comment: sorry Ollie but I can't get your problem ... and I am trying ... can you update the fiddle to the point where you find the error?

Comment: Okay, here: http://jsfiddle.net/sgm4G/ - try add/removing list elements, or just resize (vertically) the output window. You'll notice it jumps and jitters when there's not much left to scroll to after hitting the nav.